# Compute the intersection of lists for each pair of values in a column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, combinations

If I have a data set that has 2 columns user_id and their interests and I want to find users having common interests, how can I do that? For example, I will take the first user and his interests and compare it with all other user's common interests individually, then I will take the second user and compare his interests with all other user's interests and so on....

My data looks like:

```
userid   interest
 1       [A, B]
 2       [A, C, B]
 3       [B, D]
```

I am not sure how to do this-

```
for i in range(0,3):
  for j in range(i+1, 3):
    print((df['interest'].loc[i]).intersection(df['interest'].loc[j]))
```

My output should be-

```
userid    relativeid  common interest
  1          2           [A, B]
  1          3           [B]
  2          3           [B]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary to perform lookup. You can then find combinations of "userid" using `itertools.combinations` and then just perform set intersection for each "userid' list pair.

```
import itertools

m = df.set_index('userid')['interest'].map(set).to_dict()
m 
# {1: {'A', 'B'}, 2: {'A', 'B', 'C'}, 3: {'B', 'D'}}

out = pd.DataFrame(
    itertools.combinations(df.userid, 2), columns=['userid', 'relativeid'])
out['common_interest'] = [list(m[x] & m[y]) for x, y in out.values]
out

   userid  relativeid common_interest
0       1           2          [B, A]
1       1           3             [B]
2       2           3             [B]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.....but it gives me a error: data argument can't be an iterator

Comment: @user11035754 this works on 0.24. So you can instead try `pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.combinations(df.userid, 2)), ...)` (i.e., convert the iterator to a list)

Comment: This works! Can you help me to make 2 more modifications to this code:
1) This code gives a output [], B, A, [, ,] instead of just [B,A]....can you suggest something to get rid of those extra brackets.
2) what if i have words instead of just letters....like [one, two]

Comment: @user11035754 What does `df['interest'].values[0]` print? Can you please tell me? Based on this, I can tell you what to modify.

Comment: it prints this -  "['one' 'two' 'three' 'four ']"

Comment: @user11035754 Thank you. Please first run this:`import ast; df['interest']  = df['interest'].apply(ast.literal_eval)` and then run my code. The problem is you have a column of strings. You need to convert this to a column of lists.

Comment: import ast; df['interest'] = df['interest'].apply(ast.literal_eval) - This treats all the items in the list as one item. For example, df['interest'].values[0] prints 
['onetwothreefour']....and it compares this with all other interests...but I want each item in the list to be compared with all items in other lists to find common interests.

Comment: @user11035754 I see now that your lists are actually strings containing words without commas. Why?! This is unnecessarily complicating things.

Comment: I tried to modify it a bit...now when I run the code `df['interest'].values[0]` I get this- `array(['one', 'two', 'three'], dtype=object)`.........and when I run the code `import ast; df['interest'] = df['interest'].apply(ast.literal_eval)` ...I get a error- `malformed node or string: array(['one', 'two', 'three'], dtype=object)`...............is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @user11035754 Actually, the code in my answer should now work directly. Try it?

Comment: Yes it worked now....Thanks a lot....one last thing...can you explain me how this `out = pd.DataFrame(
    itertools.combinations(df.userid, 2), columns=['userid', 'relativeid'])
out['common_interest'] = [list(m[x] & m[y]) for x, y in out.values]`  actually works?

Comment: @user11035754 First, construct all combinations of userid. Let each pair by represented by (x, y). Next, for each (x, y) pair, find the corresponding list for x and y and then just find the intersection (this is done by the second line). Hope that makes it clear.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @coldspeed....can you help me solve the following one? Its an extension of this problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54933720/compute-the-intersection-of-lists-for-each-pair-of-values-in-a-column-while-reta

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would solve it, it's possible someone has a fancier `pandas` way.

```
from itertools import combinations

cs = combinations(df.userid.values, 2)
output = pd.DataFrame(list(cs), columns=['userid', 'relativeid'])

print(output)

   userid  relativeid
0       1           2
1       1           3
2       2           3


def intersect(row):
    p1 = df.loc[df.userid == row['userid'], 'interest'].values[0]
    p2 = df.loc[df.userid == row['relativeid'], 'interest'].values[0]
    return list(set(p1).intersection(set(p2)))

output.assign(common_interest=output.apply(intersect, axis=1))

   userid  relativeid common_interest
0       1           2          [B, A]
1       1           3             [B]
2       2           3             [B]
```